# Installed appx fails code integrity policy

Tags: windows, code-signing, electron-builder

I'm developing an Electron app and the current build is ready to be rolled out. I have enabled the [audit mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s?form=MY01SV&OCID=MY01SV) on a virtual machine.

This is the error I am getting in the Event viewer:

```
Code Integrity determined that a process (<path_to_system32>\svchost.exe) attempted to load <path_to_app>\my_app.exe that did not meet the Custom 1 signing level requirements or violated code integrity policy (Policy ID:{a244370e-44c9-4c06-b551-f6016e563076}). However, due to code integrity auditing policy, the image was allowed to load.
```

I've installed this app with his .appx. `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` says that my signed appx is valid.

If I run my `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` in the installed folder, my `exe` is not signed, the dlls however are correctly signed.

My second error messages looks a little bit different:

```
Code Integrity determined that a process (<path_to_app>\my_app.exe) attempted to load <path_to_app>\<some_dll>.dll that did not meet the Custom 1 signing level requirements or violated code integrity policy (Policy ID:{a244370e-44c9-4c06-b551-f6016e563076}). However, due to code integrity auditing policy, the image was allowed to load.
```

The <some_dll> are ffmpeg.dll, d3dcomiler_47.dll, swiftshader/libGLESv2.dll and swiftshader/libEGL.dll.

my package.json looks like this:

```
 "appx": {
      "identityName": "company.myapp",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "publisher": "CN=company, O=company, STREET=xxxx, L=yyyy, S=zzzz, PostalCode=1234, C=xx",
      "publisherDisplayName": "company",
      "displayName": "myapp",
      "languages": [
        "nl",
        "en",
        "fr"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "icons/icon.ico",
      "publisherName": "Company",
      "certificateFile": "./certs/certificate.p12",
      "certificatePassword": "mypassword",
      "certificateSubjectName": "company",
      "signAndEditExecutable": true,
      "signDlls": "true",
      "sign": "./customSign.js",
      "extraResources": [
        "electron/bin/*.exe"
      ],
      "verifyUpdateCodeSignature": true
    }
```

Comment: Hey. I'm still facing a very similar problem. What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey. I did saw your post before posting and the output you showed is also very similar to what I have. I'm stuck on this from yesterday and I think I have checked all the limited online source. I tried to fiddle around with my package.json but I have no idea how to go from here. According to the electron-build, Windows take care of this certification process. This is however the only incompatibility error I can reproduce. Correct me if I am wrong.

I'll keep you updated if I make any progress.